# Update partial view in the parent when it is posting

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a partial view with their respective controllers, and i want that when it is posted it redirects to the parent view with the updated form of the partial view; actually my partial form ist like so :
Partial View with Controllers

```
@*ClientConsult.cshtml*@

<form action="/partials/clientconsult" method="post">
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nroDocClient" value=@ViewData["nombre"] required>
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="RazonSocial" value="@ViewData["numeroDocumento"]">
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Direccion" value="@ViewData["direccion"]">
    <br />

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Search Client
    </button>
</form>
```

```
//GET
public IActionResult ClientConsult()
{
    ViewData["nombre"] = "";
    ViewData["numeroDocumento"] = "";
    ViewData["direccion"] = "";
    return PartialView();
}
```

```
//POST
public async Task<IActionResult> ClientConsult(string nroDocClient)
{
    var client = _context.Client.Find(1);
    ViewData["nombre"] = client.nombre;
    ViewData["numeroDocumento"] = client.numeroDocumento;
    ViewData["direccion"] = client.direccion;
    return PartialView();
}
```

My Parent View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-horizontal">
        <div>
            @{
                Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/ClientConsult.cshtml");
            }
        </div>
        <form action="/modulocertificados/createexpedient" method="post">
            <br />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nroExp" placeholder="Nro. Expediente" autofocus>
            <br />

            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                Create Expedient
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Finally when submit search client button its redirect to te form view GET but not in the parent View
, **how can i redirect to the parent view with the partialview Form updated.**
This is the page that redirects:

[image]

Comment: you will need to use ajax form for this

Comment: I have reproduced your code logic, but I have a question, why do you want to submit the search data through the parent view and then jump to the child view to perform the operation again, and then return to the parent view.

Comment: The main view is a controller to add a Expedient, but the client finder is a partial view that i want to use in this main view and others